# jQuery UI Datepicker Gravity Forms mindate 1 day after 5pm

Tags: javascript, jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to get gravity forms to stop showing next day available after 5pm of the current day. Below is what I am currently using to not show weekends and same day.

```js
<script>
function noSaturdays(date) {
    var weekday=new Array(7);
    weekday[0]="Sunday";
    weekday[1]="Monday";
    weekday[2]="Tuesday";
    weekday[3]="Wednesday";
    weekday[4]="Thursday";
    weekday[5]="Friday";
    weekday[6]="Saturday";
    //console.log(weekday[date.getDay()]);
    if(weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Saturday') {
        return [false, '', 'Not available Saturdays'];
        }else if(weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Saturday') {
                 return [false, '', 'Not available Saturdays'];
        }
 //console.log(weekday[date.getDay()]);
    if(weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Sunday') {
        return [false, '', 'Not available Sundays'];
        }else if(weekday[date.getDay()] == 'Sunday') {
                 return [false, '', 'Not available Sundays'];
        }

    return [true];
}
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('.hasDatepicker').datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', noSaturdays);
});
</script>  



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 1,dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' 

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Don't have a snippet solution for this but if you're interested in a plugin: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-limit-dates/

Comment: I am interested in your plugin. But I am not seeing if it has, Time of Day restrictions. Can you let me know if it does?

Comment: Hi Nathan, you would setup 2 Date fields, one for pre-5pm and one for post-5pm. You can use conditional logic to show the appropriate field based on the current time like so: https://gravitywiz.com/setup-time-based-conditional-logic-gravity-forms/